# bassistance jQuery Validation throwing errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Using bassistance.de's jQuery validation plugin, the validation do not always work, especially when an input that's initially been validated has its values removed.

The form will pass the validation test with the missing input, and the following error is also seen in the JS console.

**Error**

[image]

**jQuery lib**

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

**Form**

```
<form id="payment-form" class="payment-form" method="POST" action="/checkout-process">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Customer Info</legend>
        <label>Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="me@email.com">
        <label>Phone</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(function($) {

    // Validation
    $('#payment-form').validate({
        rules: {
            first_name: "required",
            last_name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            phone: {
                required: true,
                phone: true
            }
        },

        errorClass: 'alert alert-error'
    });

});
```

Comment: use a non minified version of the library while debugging, so that we can get the correct line number

Comment: I've made the change.. its on line 549

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QFWB4/1/

Comment: it looks like a problem with one of the specified rules, did you include the additional-methods.js also

Comment: line 549 says `result = $.validator.methods[method].call( this, val, element, rule.parameters );` which means one of the rule name you have specified is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the rule `phone`, there is no validation method called `phone`.

If you include the [additional-methods.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js), then you can have phone validation rules like `phoneUS`, `phoneUK`, `mobileUK`, `phoneNL` etc

Ex:

```
$(function($) {

    // Validation
    $('#payment-form').validate({
        rules: {
            first_name: "required",
            last_name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            phone: {
                required: true,
                phoneUS: true
            }
        },

        errorClass: 'alert alert-error'
    });

});
```

If none of these matches your requirement, then you may have to write a custom rule

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem... I cant seem to find a link to all the rules that comes along with the plugin

Comment: @Nyxynyx I don't think the additional-methods.js is documented properly... any way you can easily read that file to see all the available rules

Answer (score 0):

Please check the links and make sure it resolves the exact url.